# Refreshing module data on button click in react

Tags: reactjs, bind

I am new to react and using "inspirational-quotes" from https://www.npmjs.com/package/inspirational-quotes trying to load a new quote on button click using bind().
I do not know what i do wrong.
This is the code if have right now (App.js):

```
enter code here

import React, { useState } from "react";
import './App.css';

const a = 'New Quote';
const Quote = require('inspirational-quotes');
const quotes = Quote.getQuote();


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isAppon: true,
      quoteText: quotes.text,
      quoteAuthor: quotes.author
    };
    this.newQuote = this.newQuote.bind(this);
  }
  newQuote() {
    //   alert('hee')
    // this.setState({ quoteText: this.state.quoteText, quoteAuthor: this.state.quoteAuthor });
    this.setState(prevState => ({ isAppon: !prevState.isAppon }));
  }
  render() {
    return (<div className="App" >

      <header  >
        {/* <p> A new quote: {this.state.quoteText} from {this.state.quoteAuthor}</p> */}
        <button onClick={this.newQuote}> {a} < /button>
          <div> A new quote: {this.state.quoteText} from {this.state.quoteAuthor}</div>
          < /header> < /div>
          );
}

}
          export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a couple of things wrong here.

You're trying to use React Hooks (useEffect for example) in a class component, so that wont work. You'd need to use lifecycle events like `componentDidMount`.

I'm also not sure if you paste your code correctly as it isn't valid when I paste it, there are just a couple things missing but I can see what you wanted to paste so it's okay.

That said, you're also making your life difficult using a class based component when functional components are a thing in combination with hooks :)

(by the way i'm not saying class components don't have their place, they do. But they are not as beginner friendly)

Here's what you need to do:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as Quote from 'inspirational-quotes';

function App() {

  const [quote, setQuote] = useState('');
  const getNewQuote = () => {
    setQuote(Quote.getQuote())

  }

  // on mount get a new quote
  useEffect(() => {
    getNewQuote();
  }, [ ])

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={getNewQuote}>new quote</button>
      <p>{ quote.text } - { quote.author } </p>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

That said, your the library your using kinda sucks as the `getQuote` uses a "random" index that is calculated outside of the `getQuote` method. Because of this clicking the button won't create a new quote. If you can find a way to create a new instance of quote then you'll be in business. I tried a couple ways to achieve this but no luck.

I suggest looking into using a random quote API and modifying the `getNewQuote` method to use an async fetch request to get your next quote. I'll help you with this in the comments or an edit if you need.

Edit: Update as this question is based on a challenge that asks for a page refresh. See below for updated example:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Quote from 'inspirational-quotes';


const App = () => {

  const [quote, setQuote] = useState(null);
  
  const getNewQuote = () => {
    setQuote(Quote.getQuote());
  }

  // reload the current page
  const refreshPage = () => {
    window.location.reload();
  }

  // on mount get a new quote
  useEffect(() => {
    getNewQuote();
  }, [ ])

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={refreshPage}>new quote</button>
      <p>{ quote?.text } - { quote?.author } </p>
    </>
  );
}


export default App;
```

In This example we are keeping track of the quote in state using `useState` and assigning its value to `quote`.

We then use `useEffect` with an empty dependency array to tell React we want to do something when the page loads

We create two handle functions:
`getNewQuote` is for setting a quote to state (as an object).
`refreshPage` is a function to reload the current page.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I am doing a front-end developer course and this (react) is the only (last remaining) part I am having difficulties with. 
Unfortunately I have been tasked to use this particular quote library. It would be great if you can further help me out in getting it to work.

Comment: So the way imports work in React they're like a singleton. Meaning it's values won't change. So when we import `Quote` we create an `index` variable for that instance of `Quote`. Because of this no matter how many times we try re import or require the module it will always have the same `index` variable. This means we are always going to get the same quote back as the `getQuote` uses this index to grab a random quote from within range of the array of quotes that the module comes with. Can you link the course your doing? I'd like to see the requirements if possible

Comment: The course is in Dutch (https://www.nha.nl/). It is the last part of the course. I will try to translate the final task in this project: - After installing the NPM module "inspirational-quotes ", you update the App.js with the quotes. Inside the existing function, you write a new function with a button which generates a page refresh and consequently a new quote. -

Comment: In the react part of the course, I have learned about props, state, bind(), events and objects. I thought this taks had to been completed utilising props and bind(). That is the reason for the code I wrote. However you are right in using the function in your code reply.

Comment: Oh it's just a page refresh, that makes it easier for you then. I'll update the example

Comment: Check my edit to the question, does this help?

Comment: Accept my answer so I can get those sweet sweet internet points? :)